# How does the Icelandic word "finna" come from Proto-Germanic "finþanan"?

Tags: sound-change, germanic-languages, old-norse

[***finna***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/finna#Etymology)

> From Old Norse **finna**, from Proto-Germanic ***finþanan**.

[***finþanan***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Germanic/fin%C3%BEanan)

> From Proto-Indo-European ***pent-, *penth-** (“to go, pass; path, bridge”). Cognate with Latin pons (“bridge”), Old Indian pánthā (“way, path”).
>
> Related also to Old High German fendo, fendeo (“pedestrian, footsoldier”), Old Saxon fāþi (“walking”), Old English fēþe (“locomotion, walking, gait, pace”)
>
> Descendants
>   Old English: findan
>   Scots: find, fynd
>   English: find
>   Old Saxon: findan
>   Old Dutch: *findan
>   Dutch: vinden
>   Afrikaans: vind
>   Old High German: findan
>   Middle High German: vinden
>   German: finden
>   Old Norse: **finna**
>   Icelandic: **finna**
>   Faroese: **finna**
>   Swedish: **finna**
>   Danish: finde
>   Norwegian: **finne**
>   Gothic:  (finþan)

I guess there must have existed some common changes in the Old Norse branch, for the daughter languages of that branch altogether lost the "d".

Does anyone know what the name of these phenomena?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of these look like regular sound changes between Proto-Germanic and Old Norse. However, I have found no eponyms for these sound changes, if that was what you were asking.

## Loss of word-final /nan/

[Wikipedia gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=North_Germanic_languages&oldid=516166594#Unique_North_Germanic_features) this as an example of an innovation in North Germanic:

> General loss of word-final /n/, following the loss of word-final short vowels (which are still present in the earliest runic inscriptions).
>
> > Proto-Germanic **bindanaN* > **bindan* > Old Norse *binda*, but > Old English *bindan*

Applying this rule to **finþanan* gives **finþa*.

## Assimilation of /nþ/ to /nn/

This is also a regular sound change in Old Norse. [According to Marisa Lohr](http://web.archive.org/web/20090305100852/http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Emarisal/ie/ngmc.html), one of its characteristic innovations is:

> Development of /lth/ and /nth/ to /ll nn/ eg. ON finna, past pl. fundinn "to find"; ON gull, OE gold

This same phenomenon appears in many other ON words, such as [*tǫnn*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C7%ABnn#Old_Norse) 'tooth', from Proto-Germanic *[*tanþs*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Germanic/tan%C3%BEs), [*gunnr*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gunnr#Old%20Norse) 'war' from **gunþiz*, *munnr* 'mouth' from **munþaz*. (Note that English instead lost the /n/.)

Comment: Your answer is exactly what I want to know, thank you!!!

Comment: Strange, my dictionary says ON muðr for mouth... anyway, it agrees with tǫnn. But I wonder then, where the d in Danish "mund" and "tand" come from, if ON already lost them. Maybe German influence, or some kind of "etymologic spelling"?

Comment: Oh, it's not pronounced by the way, and "mun" in modern Danish would create a long "u", so maybe it was added instead of another "n" as a spelling convention (inspired by etymology).

Comment: Danish has <nd> for Old Norse (and Old Danish) _-nn-_ as a way to mark palatalization. Modern Danish has lost the palatalization again.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *muðr* from *munnr* exhibits an additional later change like that in *maðr* "man" from **mannr*. Somehow geminated *n* before the *z*-derived *r* realized as *ð*. So it would PG **munþaz* to proto-ON **munnr* to later ON *muðr*.

Comment: That change takes place regardless what the origin of the _r_ is (i.e. not only the _r_ that comes from _z_). This was addressed in http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/why-does-the-old-norse-word-madr-include-d-while-its-cognate-e-man-doesn/2882#2882