# Why does the Old Norse word "maðr" include "ð", while its cognate E "man" doesn't?

Tags: sound-change, germanic-languages, old-norse

[***maðr***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%B0r)

> From Proto-Germanic ***mann-**, whence also Old English mann, Old High German man.

[***mann-***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aProto-Germanic/mann-)

> Descendants
>   Old English: *mann, man; manna*
>   English: *man*
>   Old Frisian: *man, mon*
>   West Frisian: *man*
>   Old Saxon: *man*
>   Old Dutch: *man*
>   Dutch: *man, men*
>   Afrikaans: *man*
>   Old High German: *man*
>   German: *Mann, man*
>   Old Norse: **maðr**
>   Icelandic: **maður**
>   Faroese: **maður**
>   Norwegian: *mann*
>   Old Swedish: **maþer, mander, man**
>   Swedish: *man*
>   Old Danish: *man*
>   Danish: **mand**
>   Gothic: (*manna*)

Old Norse must have undergone some kind of sound change, otherwise the "*d*" would be remained in other branches, including English.

Or it is just an element form another Old Norse word? 
Moreover, the *"r"* is also unknown to me.

Is there any other example?

Comment: the cluster -nr- often becomes -ndr- with epenthetic /d/.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thank you!! Another problem to me is the intrusive "r", I hope to find out why it's also there.

Comment: That's not intrusive - **-r** is a masculine nominative infection in e.g. Old Norse.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Thanks a lot, the function of "r" becomes clear, Thank you again!

Comment: Interesting. Sort of the opposite of http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2650/how-does-the-icelandic-word-finna-come-from-proto-germanic-finanan.

Comment: Is the Proto-Germanic not *mannaz, where -az is the masculine nominative ending and transformed to -(a)r in Old Norse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Old Norse, the sequence *-nnr(-)* becomes *-ðr(-)*. It's just a rule of Old Norse. You'll find it described in any grammar of Old Norse.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this was answered a long time ago, I feel there is a need for clarification. As Sverre mentioned, *-nnr-* becomes *-ðr-* in **Old Norse** per regular rule, but this is often avoided: words like **Proto-Germanic** *­*hanþaz* (clever, sharp, "quick") gave Old Norse *hannr*, then *­*swinþaz* (strong) giving *svinnr*, as well as *­*minniz* (small in quantity) giving *minnr*.  This isn't that frequent, with not a lot of words featuring no alternative form that has -*ðr*-. It's also noteworthy that many Norse words can take either the -*ðr*- or -*nnr*- form and in many cases they can even alternate without any visible pattern. **Icelandic** and **Faroese** usually have words that reflect the -*nnr*- variety but -*ðr*- can also sometimes pop up here and there, and, even in some cases, such as with "annar" in both languages, we can see a complex (yet in this case regular) alternation between the two forms.

Comment: You also find _sviðr_ and _miðr_. _svinnr_ and _minnr_ have an analogically reinstated _nn_ from other forms of the paradigm. There is, as far as I know, no Old Norse word _*hannr_.

Comment: I wasn't aware of **sviðr** and **miðr**, and **hannr** is attested as part of **sjónhannr** as I've seen here: http://books.google.de/books?id=Bc0fAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA280&lpg=PA280&dq=sj%C3%B3nhannr&source=bl&ots=-wwjzsIqgV&sig=7ojbOiOXMWDRpGCuPoDpj0eTwZc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iwhiVNLvPIvkaJnQgdgP&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=sj%C3%B3nhannr&f=false

Comment: _Miðr_ even exists in Modern Icelandic as a perfectly normal word: it’s the second part of the very common expression _því miður_ ‘unfortunately’. It’s not part of the ‘less’ paradigm, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that *miður* looks like it's etymologically from **midjaz*, though; it's not cognate

Comment: @Darkgamma I don’t think so. I realise Wiktionary says so, but I don’t think it’s right. That’s a different _miður_, which means (and is cognate with) ‘middle’. It would be highly unexpected if this _miður_ were etymologically the same, given all the other comparatives of _lítill/lítt_ which have _minn-_ as their root. Incidentally, I was wrong before: _miður_ isn’t part of the adjectival _minni_ (‘less’, comparative of _lítill_) paradigm, but it is the comparative of adverbial _lítt_, so it is part of the ‘less’ paradigm; the superlative is _minnst_.

Comment: I just checked Zoëga's, and *miðr* 'middle' is indeed from a different etymology from *miðr* 'worse' (=minnr); semantic shifts aside (as there can be a rational explanation even with those changes in semantics), you're right about that one